# How to loop audio clip in unity infinitely

Tags: loops, unity-game-engine, audioclip

I set my audio clip to loop (by checking off the loop checkbox in the audio source) however, after about an hour the audio stops playing. How do I fix this? Is there code that I have to add to the script?

Apparently the loop function is not indefinite.. not too sure about this.

Thank you!!

Comment: Maybe you changed something in the source or listener and it is not because of the loop

Comment: hm I'm not sure about that because it loops for a long time before stopping and nothing has changed to make it stop

Answer (score 0):

If your sound file is an .mp3, try changing it to an .ogg file. Unity seems to have some problems with .mp3.

Also, it could be simply be a lack of computing resources to run in play mode that long. Try building your application and seeing if the error still occurs.